# Js - Loop through array to create inputs and values only filling last item input value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with id="inputs" on html and the following code on js:

```
let paises=[
    {pais: "Honduras",scripttag:`<script src="perro loco come baba"> 'cha cha'` },
    {pais: "Chile",scripttag:"perropapa"},
    {pais: "Madagascar",scripttag:"otro"}
]
let inputDiv=document.getElementById("inputs")
for(let p of paises){
    if(p.scripttag){
        inputDiv.innerHTML+=`<input disabled id="` + p.pais + `">`
        let inputPais=document.getElementById(p.pais)
        inputPais.value=p.scripttag
    }
}
```

If the element of the paises array has a scripttag property, an input is created and value is filled with scripttag content.

Inputs get created properly, the issue is that in the page all the inputs are empty except the last one created (on this case the input with id Madagascar is filled with "otro")

Comment: It's because you are editing the same element everytime. You see the last value it's because it is the last updated value

Comment: Shouldn't inputPais store the new input created on each iteration?

Comment: you have to create a new element each loop

Comment: Think of it this way: let randomVariable = 5
with you for in loop you do this:
randomVariable = 10
randomVariable = 15
randomVariable = 20

because you don't do anything with updated values until the end, what happens is that  we update the variable 3 times and when it is 20, we send it inside the HTML tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not creating a new element every time you want to add a new input.

Instead of adding html to divs like that, you can make use of [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).

```js
let paises=[
    {pais: "Honduras",scripttag:`<script src="perro loco come baba"> 'cha cha'` },
    {pais: "Chile",scripttag:"perropapa"},
    {pais: "Madagascar",scripttag:"otro"}
]
let inputDiv=document.getElementById("inputs")
for(let p of paises){
    if(p.scripttag){
        const newInput = document.createElement('input')
        newInput.id = p.pais
        newInput.value = p.scripttag
        inputDiv.appendChild(newInput)
    }
}
```

This way you are adding a new element to the div each loop. Instead of overwriting the previous element. I also think you have more control over the inputs properties using DOM manipulation instead writing everything out in a string and concating.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: awesome, if it is the correct solution for you please mark it as accepted and we can close this out.

Comment: How was OP resetting innerHTML with `inputDiv.innerHTML+=`?

Comment: sorry bad wording, good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that you could just set the value with the HTML you are generating.

```js
let paises=[
    {pais: "Honduras",scripttag:`<script src='perro loco come baba'/> 'cha cha'` },
    {pais: "Chile",scripttag:"perropapa"},
    {pais: "Madagascar",scripttag:"otro"}
]
let inputDiv=document.getElementById("inputs")
for(let p of paises){
    if(p.scripttag){
        inputDiv.innerHTML+=`<input disabled id="${p.pais}" value="${p.scripttag}">`
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='inputs'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let paises=[
    {pais: "Honduras",scripttag:`<script src="perro loco come baba"> 'cha cha'` },
    {pais: "Chile",scripttag:"perropapa"},
    {pais: "Madagascar",scripttag:"otro"}
]
let inputDiv=document.getElementById("inputs")
for(let p of paises){
    if(p.scripttag){
        inputDiv.innerHTML= inputDiv.innerHTML +`<input disabled='true' id="` + p.pais + `" value='${p. scripttag}'/>`
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs"></div>
```